# Burninate the api tag

Tags: support, burninate-request

May [api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) be burninated? It is currently used in 126 questions, but that tag is not helpful at all. Knowing the question is about an API doesn't change the given answer, nor are there API experts who are following it.

Comment: +1 The are more API's than you can shake a stick at with Druapl, especially if you include contrib APIs.  I also REALLY hope you were referencing [Trogdor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoARQRCvpQU) :)

Comment: Agreed.  @Chapabu, "burninate" is the official term to delete a tag from existence" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/the-true-meaning-of-burninate

Comment: @MPD I guessed what it meant, I was just wondering if it originated from Trogdor/Strongbad =)  Looks like it probably does..that is neat =)

Comment: @Chapabu Actually, _burninate_ means removing it from the existing questions. It is removed from the history of each question, and it appears as it has never been used. It is different from editing each question using it, as that would leave a track in the revisions; plus, burninating a tag doesn't bump questions as an edit would. There is still the possibility somebody uses the tag in a new question, though. Burninating is the first step; black-listing is the second one, if the tag keeps to be used.